# How to use MTLBlitCommandEncoder without the use of MTLBuffer

Tags: rendering, metal, renderer

I've read in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder) that the MTLBlitCommandEncoder should be used when trying to copy between buffers. However, I've been working with smaller than 4K buffers and have been calling [setVertexBytes of the MTLRenderCommandEncoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder). Since the MTLBlitCommandEncoder only works with MTLBuffers, is the use of this encoder needed to copy buffers? Does Apple have any sort of documentation about trying to copy UnsafeRawPointers instead? Are there any downsides, in terms of memory, to using MTLBuffers?

Answer (score 0):

In your case (**4Kb buffers**) it would be better to perform copying on CPU.
To copy data between two raw pointer’s buffers you should use the following [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/copymemory(from:bytecount:)):

```
copyMemory(from:byteCount:)
```

Comment: So there's nothing that requires to be done specifically on the encoder? I can safely copy memory without it?